# How to override html td also with padding color?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I wish to make cell d with full yellow background.

How can I do that?

I am targeting the html in outlook display.

http://jsfiddle.net/f2pb227a/

Update 1: actually, I am using agility html pack to change the cell d at runtime and the table is already well formatted, for some reasons, I just wish change the cell d at last step, therefore, I want to use div to insert yellow bg without change it parent td class.

**Final solution: https://jsfiddle.net/0khjqdh0/**

```
<table class="XXX" >
    <tr class="header">
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d1">
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d0">
        <td>c
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div class="special_class"> d </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



.XXX table{
    border:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    padding:0px;
}

.XXX tr.header td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10.0pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#4F81BD;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    padding:5px;
}
.XXX tr.d0 td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10.0pt;
    background-color:#E1EEF4;
    border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
    padding:5px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.XXX tr.d1 td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10.0pt;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
    padding:5px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.XXX div.special_class {
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy, please check this  - http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/f2pb227a/4/

```
.XXX div.special_class {
  background-color:yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the class on the cell:

```
<td class="special_class">
  <div> d </div>
</td>
```

Then set the style on the cell and make it specific enought to override the existing style:

```
.XXX tr.d0 td.special_class {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f2pb227a/1/

Comment: thank you. but I am not able to change its parent of td class. any chance to use div ?

Comment: but your answer must be helpful to others who can change <td>

Comment: @DayDayHappy: Then you need to remove the padding on the cells, and put elements in all the cells that you can add padding to instead. When the cells have no padding, the div inside them can fill up the cell.

Answer (score 0):

try to apply `background-color:yellow;` to parent td or remove padding from td cell and give that padding to child div

Comment: actually it doesn't work because it will just add more padding. thanks anyway. https://jsfiddle.net/f2pb227a/3/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give class not to child element of the `td`, but to exact `td` who's background-color you want to change:

```
<td class="special_class">
```